# Content Dialog with Map Control Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, bing-maps

Content Dialog in windows Phone 8.1 doesn't allow to add map control in XAML , when you added it and run the project the app crashing with **Catastrophic failure**
 exception.

```
<ContentDialog 
xmlns:Maps="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps" 
x:Class="example.ContentDialogexample"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"       
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="">
<StackPanel>
        <Maps:MapControl MapServiceToken="MapKey" />
</StackPanel>
</ContentDialog>
```

Comment: So what's your question? How to make `MapControl` shown in a `ContentDialog` in WP8.1 app?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT    Yes that right

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it crashes, but the reality is that you shouldn't load the map inside of any kind of dialog or popup. The map uses a lot of resources and also generates a billable transaction every time it is loaded. Using it in a dialog or popup likely means that the map will be loaded and disposed a lot. This would generate a lot of billable transactions and you will end up exceeding the free limits very fast and then licensing would likely cost a lot as the number of transactions would likely be very high.

Comment: Thanks for your description